# Change bootstrap button colour and class on click or on hover/focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

1. I have four bootstrap buttons with btn-primary class set on them.
   On hover or focus I would like to change the color of the button to show that on hover or focus is happening.
2. On clicking a button I would like to set btn-danger bootstrap class. I already have an ng-click event attached to the buttons so not sure how I can get a handle to the button and change the css only on that button. The examples I have seen have a jquery click event handler but not sure if that is the best approach to take

Please can you advice how to go about the above two queries?

```
<div>
<br>
&nbsp;
<button type="button" class="btn  btn-primary" ng-click="pendingReqCtrl.loadData('Create')">Create Requests
       </button>
&nbsp;
<button type="button" class="btn  btn-primary" ng-click="pendingReqCtrl.loadData('Update')">Update Requests
       </button>
&nbsp;
<button type="button" class="btn  btn-primary" ng-click="pendingReqCtrl.loadData('Activate')">Activation
    Requests
       </button>
&nbsp;
<button type="button" class="btn  btn-primary" ng-click="pendingReqCtrl.loadData('Deactivate')">Deactivation
    Requests
       </button>
</div>
```

Comment: What color do you want to change each button to on hover? They should be darkening ever so slightly already.

Comment: I agree that there is a slight change in colour on hover that bootstrap offers. I would like to make it a bit more apparent with the colour change on hover or focus.

Comment: you can do css way. why you trying by js?. Anyway use ng-class for condition based changing css class.

Answer (score 1):

```
<button type="button" class="btn" ng-class="{ 'btn-primary': !pendingReqCtrl.isButtonHover,  'someClass': pendingReqCtrl.isButtonHover, 'btn-danger': pendingReqCtrl.isClick" ng-mouseover="onMouseOver(true)" ng-mouseleave="onMouseOver(false)" ng-click="pendingReqCtrl.loadData('Create')">Create Requests
   </button>

function onMouseOver(isHover){
    pendingReqCtrl.isButtonHover = isHover;
 }

function loadData(){
    pendingReqCtrl.isClick= true;
}
```

Try something like this.

Answer (score 0):

As a best practice you should override bootstrap styles (rather than edit them directly). To override the bootstrap's `btn-primary:hover` styles, add this to your own custom stylesheet.

```
.btn-primary:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #286090; /* new color goes her */
    border-color: #204d74;
}
```

and this to override the `btn-primary:focus` styles:

```
.btn-primary.focus, .btn-primary:focus {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #286090; /* new color goes her */
    border-color: #122b40;
}
```

Just make sure that your own stylesheet with these overrides comes after the bootstrap stylesheet.

UPDATE

To limit this to only those buttons you can give the surrounding div an `id="myButtons"` and then the css overrides can become

```
#myButtons .btn-primary:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #286090; /* new color goes her */
    border-color: #204d74;
}

#myButtons .btn-primary.focus, .btn-primary:focus {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #286090; /* new color goes her */
    border-color: #122b40;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Matthew. I have other pages which use btn-primary that don't need similar behaviour on hover or on focus. So is there a way to only specify the bootstrap overrides to the 4 buttons above?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this: give an id to the button that you want to change the css and then call it from your controller.

Suppose your button id is `buttonId`, then from the controller

```
document.getElementById('buttonId').style.color = 'blue'
document.getElementById('buttonId').style.width = value
```